# Made a simple platformer game in arcade library of Python

Tags: python, performance, object-oriented, game

This is a simple game I am making in the arcade library of Python. I am quite new to object-oriented programming as well as game development. I feel like a lot of the code is inefficient, so I was hoping to get some improvements on the code. Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

```
import os
import random
import arcade

SPRITE_SCALING = 0.5
SPRITE_SCALING_COIN = 0.3
SPRITE_NATIVE_SIZE = 128
SPRITE_SIZE = int(SPRITE_NATIVE_SIZE * SPRITE_SCALING)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN_TITLE = "Help Nick Adams!"

# Physics
MOVEMENT_SPEED = 5
JUMP_SPEED = 12
GRAVITY = 0.5


class Room:
    # Class to hold info about rooms/levels

    def __init__(self):
        self.wall_list = self.goal_list = self.enemy_list = self.victory_sprite = None
        self.collectedCoins = 0
        self.numCoins = 0
        self.background = None


def setup_room_1():
    room = Room()
    room.wall_list = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)
    room.enemy_list = arcade.SpriteList()
    room.goal_list = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)
    room.victory_sprite = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)

    # Draw platforms and ground
    for x in range(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SPRITE_SIZE):
        wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/grassMid.png", SPRITE_SCALING)

        wall.bottom = 0
        wall.left = x
        room.wall_list.append(wall)

    for x in range(SPRITE_SIZE * 3, SPRITE_SIZE * 8, SPRITE_SIZE):
        wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/grassMid.png", SPRITE_SCALING)

        wall.bottom = SPRITE_SIZE * 3
        wall.left = x
        room.wall_list.append(wall)

    # Draw the crates
    for x in range(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SPRITE_SIZE * 5):
        wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/boxCrate_double.png", SPRITE_SCALING)

        wall.bottom = SPRITE_SIZE
        wall.left = x
        room.wall_list.append(wall)

    # Draw an enemy 1
    enemy = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/enemies/wormGreen.png", SPRITE_SCALING)

    enemy.bottom = SPRITE_SIZE
    enemy.left = SPRITE_SIZE * 2

    enemy.change_x = 2
    room.enemy_list.append(enemy)

    # -- Draw enemy2 on the platform
    enemy = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/enemies/wormGreen.png", SPRITE_SCALING)

    enemy.bottom = SPRITE_SIZE * 4
    enemy.left = SPRITE_SIZE * 4

    # Set boundaries for enemy
    enemy.boundary_right = SPRITE_SIZE * 8
    enemy.boundary_left = SPRITE_SIZE * 3
    enemy.change_x = 2
    room.enemy_list.append(enemy)

    # Set up coins
    for pos in [[128, 96], [418, 300], [670, 150]]:
        goal = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/items/coinGold.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
        goal.center_x = pos[0]
        goal.center_y = pos[1]
        room.goal_list.append(goal)
        room.numCoins += 1

    # Set up checkpoint/level clear
    flag = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/signExit.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
    flag.center_x = 770
    flag.center_y = 96
    room.victory_sprite.append(flag)

    # Load the background image for this level.
    room.background = arcade.load_texture(":resources:images/backgrounds/abstract_1.jpg")

    return room


def setup_room_2():
    room = Room()
    room.wall_list = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)
    room.enemy_list = arcade.SpriteList()
    room.goal_list = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)
    room.victory_sprite = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)

    # Set up walls
    for y in range(0, 800, 200):
        for x in range(100, 700, 64):
            wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/boxCrate_double.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
            wall.center_x = x
            wall.center_y = y
            room.wall_list.append(wall)

    for pos in [[35, 40], [765, 80], [35, 280], [765, 480]]:
        wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/grassHalf.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
        wall.center_x = pos[0]
        wall.center_y = pos[1]
        room.wall_list.append(wall)

    # Create the coins
    for i in range(50):

        # Create the coin instance
        # Coin image from kenney.nl
        goal = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/items/coinGold.png", SPRITE_SCALING_COIN)

        # Boolean variable if we successfully placed the coin
        coin_placed_successfully = False

        # Keep trying until success
        while not coin_placed_successfully:
            # Position the coin
            goal.center_x = random.randrange(100, 700)
            goal.center_y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

            # See if the coin is hitting a wall
            wall_hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(goal, room.wall_list)

            # See if the coin is hitting another coin
            coin_hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(goal, room.goal_list)

            if len(wall_hit_list) == 0 and len(coin_hit_list) == 0:
                coin_placed_successfully = True
                room.numCoins += 1

        # Add the coin to the lists
        room.goal_list.append(goal)

    # Draw an enemy1
    enemy = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/enemies/fly.png", SPRITE_SCALING_COIN)

    enemy.bottom = SPRITE_SIZE
    enemy.left = SPRITE_SIZE * 2

    enemy.boundary_right = SPRITE_SIZE * 8 + 60
    enemy.boundary_left = SPRITE_SIZE * 1 + 60
    enemy.change_x = 3
    room.enemy_list.append(enemy)

    # Draw a enemy2
    enemy = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/enemies/fly.png", SPRITE_SCALING_COIN)

    enemy.bottom = SPRITE_SIZE * 4
    enemy.left = SPRITE_SIZE * 4

    enemy.boundary_right = SPRITE_SIZE * 8
    enemy.boundary_left = SPRITE_SIZE * 3
    enemy.change_x = 4
    room.enemy_list.append(enemy)

    # Draw a enemy3
    enemy = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/enemies/fly.png", SPRITE_SCALING_COIN)

    enemy.bottom = SPRITE_SIZE * 7.2
    enemy.left = SPRITE_SIZE * 4

    enemy.boundary_right = SPRITE_SIZE * 8 + 80
    enemy.boundary_left = SPRITE_SIZE * 3
    enemy.change_x = 5.2
    room.enemy_list.append(enemy)

    # Draw victory point
    flag = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/signExit.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
    flag.center_x = 765
    flag.center_y = 545
    room.victory_sprite.append(flag)

    # Load the background image for this level.
    room.background = arcade.load_texture(":resources:images/backgrounds/abstract_1.jpg")

    return room


def setup_room_3():
    room = Room()
    room.wall_list = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)
    room.goal_list = arcade.SpriteList()
    room.victory_sprite = arcade.SpriteList(use_spatial_hash=True)

    # Draw boundaries
    for y in (0, SCREEN_HEIGHT - SPRITE_SIZE):
        # Loop for each box going across
        for x in range(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SPRITE_SIZE):
            wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/stoneCenter.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
            wall.left = x
            wall.bottom = y
            room.wall_list.append(wall)

        # Create left and right column of boxes
    for x in (0, SCREEN_WIDTH - SPRITE_SIZE):
        # Loop for each box going across
        for y in range(SPRITE_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT - SPRITE_SIZE, SPRITE_SIZE):
            wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/stoneCenter.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
            wall.left = x
            wall.bottom = y
            room.wall_list.append(wall)

    # Create boxes in the middle
    for x in range(128, SCREEN_WIDTH, 134):
        for y in range(140, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 50, 170):
            wall = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/tiles/brickGrey.png", 0.4)
            wall.center_x = x
            wall.center_y = y
            # wall.angle = 45
            room.wall_list.append(wall)

    # Create coins
    for i in range(50):
        coin = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/enemies/fishPink.png", 0.25)
        coin.center_x = random.randrange(100, 700)
        coin.center_y = random.randrange(100, 500)
        while coin.change_x == 0 and coin.change_y == 0:
            coin.change_x = random.randrange(-4, 5)
            coin.change_y = random.randrange(-4, 5)

        room.goal_list.append(coin)

    room.background = arcade.load_texture(":resources:images/backgrounds/abstract_1.jpg")

    return room


class MainGame(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)

        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.chdir(file_path)

        # Sprites and set up player
        self.player_list = self.rooms = self.player_sprite = self.physics_engine = None
        self.current_room = self.view_left = self.view_bottom = self.collectedCoins = self.score = 0
        self.game_over = False

        # Load sounds
        self.collect_goal_sound = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/coin1.wav")
        self.jump_sound = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/jump1.wav")

        # Starting room number
        self.current_room = 2

        # list of rooms
        self.rooms = []

        # Create the rooms
        room = setup_room_1()
        self.rooms.append(room)

        room = setup_room_2()
        self.rooms.append(room)

        room = setup_room_3()
        self.rooms.append(room)

        self.totalScore = 0

        self.set_mouse_visible(False)

    def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game and initialize the variables. """
        self.score = 0

        # -- Set up the player
        self.player_sprite = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/animated_characters/female_person/femalePerson_idle.png",
                                           SPRITE_SCALING)

        # Player start position according to room number
        if self.current_room == 0:
            self.player_sprite.center_x = 64
            self.player_sprite.center_y = 270
        elif self.current_room == 1:
            self.player_sprite.center_x = 35
            self.player_sprite.center_y = 55
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.player_list.append(self.player_sprite)

        if self.current_room == 2:
            self.player_sprite = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/animated_characters/female_person"
                                               "/femalePerson_climb0.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
            self.player_sprite.center_x = 340
            self.player_sprite.center_y = 300
            self.player_list.append(self.player_sprite)

        # Create a physics engine
        self.physics_engine = arcade.PhysicsEnginePlatformer(self.player_sprite,
                                                             self.rooms[self.current_room].wall_list)

    def on_draw(self):

        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_lrwh_rectangle_textured(0, 0,
                                            SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                                            self.rooms[self.current_room].background)

        self.rooms[self.current_room].wall_list.draw()
        self.rooms[self.current_room].goal_list.draw()
        if self.current_room != 2:
            self.rooms[self.current_room].enemy_list.draw()
            self.rooms[self.current_room].victory_sprite.draw()

        if self.current_room == 0:
            arcade.draw_text("Help Nick collect items for his coffee!", 250, 570, arcade.color.BLACK, 20)
        elif self.current_room == 1:
            arcade.draw_text("Help Nick collect grasshoppers!", 250, 570, arcade.color.BLACK, 20)
        elif self.current_room == 2:
            arcade.draw_text("Help Nick collect all the fish (use your mouse to catch them)", 250, 570,
                             arcade.color.BLACK, 20)

        output1 = f"Score: {self.score}"
        arcade.draw_text(output1, 10, 560, arcade.color.WHITE, 14)
        output2 = f"Total Score: {self.totalScore}"
        arcade.draw_text(output2, 10, 540, arcade.color.WHITE, 14)
        # Draw all the sprites.
        self.player_list.draw()

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        if key == arcade.key.UP:
            if self.physics_engine.can_jump():
                self.player_sprite.change_y = JUMP_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = -MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = MOVEMENT_SPEED

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):
        if key == arcade.key.LEFT or key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = 0

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        if self.current_room == 2:
            self.player_sprite.center_x = x
            self.player_sprite.center_y = y

    def on_update(self, delta_time):

        if not self.game_over:
            if self.current_room == 0 or self.current_room == 1:
                # Move the enemies
                self.rooms[self.current_room].enemy_list.update()

                # Check each enemy
                for enemy in self.rooms[self.current_room].enemy_list:
                    # If the enemy hit a wall, reverse
                    if len(arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(enemy, self.rooms[self.current_room].wall_list)) > 0:
                        enemy.change_x *= -1
                    # If the enemy hit the left boundary, reverse
                    elif enemy.boundary_left is not None and enemy.left < enemy.boundary_left:
                        enemy.change_x *= -1
                    # If the enemy hit the right boundary, reverse
                    elif enemy.boundary_right is not None and enemy.right > enemy.boundary_right:
                        enemy.change_x *= -1

                # Update the player using the physics engine
                self.physics_engine.update()

                # See if we hit any coins
                goal_hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite,
                                                                     self.rooms[self.current_room].goal_list)

                # Loop through each coin we hit (if any) and remove it
                for goal in goal_hit_list:
                    # Remove the coin
                    goal.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                    # Play a sound
                    arcade.play_sound(self.collect_goal_sound)
                    # Count number of coins collected
                    self.collectedCoins += 1
                    self.score += 1
                    self.totalScore += 1

                if self.player_sprite.center_x <= -10 or self.player_sprite.center_x >= 800:
                    self.player_sprite.change_x = 0
                    self.player_sprite.change_y = 0
                    self.player_sprite.center_x = 64
                    self.player_sprite.center_y = 270

                # See if the player hit a worm
                if len(arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite,
                                                            self.rooms[self.current_room].enemy_list)) > 0:
                    self.game_over = True

                # See if the player hit the flag. If so, progress to next level
                if arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite, self.rooms[
                    self.current_room].victory_sprite) and self.collectedCoins >= self.rooms[
                     self.current_room].numCoins:
                    # self.game_over = True
                    self.current_room += 1
                    self.setup()

            elif self.current_room == 2:

                for coin in self.rooms[self.current_room].goal_list:
                    coin.center_x += coin.change_x
                    walls_hit = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(coin, self.rooms[self.current_room].wall_list)
                    for wall in walls_hit:
                        if coin.change_x > 0:
                            coin.right = wall.left
                        elif coin.change_x < 0:
                            coin.left = wall.right
                    if len(walls_hit) > 0:
                        coin.change_x *= -1

                    coin.center_y += coin.change_y
                    walls_hit = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(coin, self.rooms[self.current_room].wall_list)
                    for wall in walls_hit:
                        if coin.change_y > 0:
                            coin.top = wall.bottom
                        elif coin.change_y < 0:
                            coin.bottom = wall.top
                    if len(walls_hit) > 0:
                        coin.change_y *= -1

                # Generate a list of all sprites that collided with the player.
                hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite,
                                                                self.rooms[self.current_room].goal_list)

                # Loop through each colliding sprite, remove it, and add to the score.
                for coin in hit_list:
                    coin.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                    arcade.play_sound(self.collect_goal_sound)
                    self.score += 1
                    self.totalScore += 1
                    if self.score >= 50:
                        self.game_over = True
                        self.current_room = 0
                        self.setup()


def main():
    window = MainGame()
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

All the `range(0, number)` can be simplified to just `range(number)`.

---

You can change

```
if self.current_room == 0 or self.current_room == 1:
```

to

```
if self.current_room in [0, 1]:
```

---

```
if len(wall_hit_list) == 0 and len(coin_hit_list) == 0:
```

can be

```
if not wall_hit_list and not coin_hit_list:
```

---

You can change

```
if len(arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite,
                                            self.rooms[self.current_room].enemy_list)) > 0:
    self.game_over = True
```

to

```
if arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite, self.rooms[self.current_room].enemy_list):
    self.game_over = True
```

---

Comment: `if not (wall_hit_list or coin_hit_list):` using de morgan's law